# Hadoop YARN simple yarn application

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run the simple yarn application listed here: https://github.com/hortonworks/simple-yarn-app

I am a beginner with both Java and Hadoop, and when I try to compile the simple yarn Client file using '`javac`', I get the following error:

Client.java:9: `error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist`

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
```

The command I am using to compile the file is:

```
javac Client.java
```

I have Googled this error to see if I could find which JAR file is missing from my classpath, but I couldn't find anything helpful with respect to YARN. Most of the results were related to `HBASE`, `PIG` or `HIVE`.

Can someone please point me towards the relevant JAR file I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Rizvi for suggesting the edit. Looks much more readable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I didn't need to manually add JAR files to the classpath. I simply used the command **'bin/hadoop classpath'**. It automatically adds the required JAR files.

The command used to compile the file:

```
# javac -cp `$HADOOP_HOME\bin\hadoop classpath` Client.java
```

Comment: Could you please share me the running procedure as well?

Comment: Hey, to run this example: 
(1) Clone the repo
(2) Use maven to make the package
(3) Follow the commands in the README file provided with the repo

Answer (score 2):

Add hadoop jars in your classpath:

```
HADOOP_CLIENT=/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20
HADOOP_LIB=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib

for i in ${HADOOP_CLIENT}/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

for i in ${HADOOP_LIB}/*.jar ; do
    CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$i
done

javac -cp $CLASSPATH yourclass.java
```

Save it as runScript.sh and run it.

Comment: I tried looking up the hadoop core JAR file in the Hadoop package I have, but I couldn't find any. There were a bunch of other JAR files though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the error still remains. I have added all the JAR files from the directory: **$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib**

I am now going to try and use **jar -tf** command to see if I can look inside the JAR files for the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I have resolved the issue. Let me update the answer myself. Thank you again, much appreciated.